# Splice a string, multiple times, using a keyword

Tags: python

I am trying to break a string apart by removing segments that occur between two words.

Example:

```
AGCGUGUGAGAGCUCCGA
```

I will remove the parts that occur between: GUGU and AGAG

So, the new string will be:

```
AGCCUCCGA
```

I wrote a code that utilises while loop to keep 'splicing' a string over and over till it can't find the GUGU and AGAG in the string. The process works, most of the time.

I encountered one case where the 'input' is extremely long and then my code is stuck in an infinite loop and I don't understand why that is the case.

I was hoping that someone could review it and help me improve on what I am doing.

```
def splice(strand):
    while True:
        initial = strand.find('GUGU')
        final = strand.find('AGAG')
        if initial == -1:
            break
        if final == -1:
            break
        strand = strand[:initial] + strand[final+4:]
    return strand

if __name__ == "__main__":
    strand = input("Input strand: ")
    print()
    spliced = splice(strand)
    print("Output is {}".format(spliced))
```

The case where it is failing is:

```
GUGUAGAGGUCACAGUGUAAAAGCUCUAGAGCAGACAGAUGUAGAGGUGUUGUGUAACCCGUAGAGCAAAGGCAACAGUGUGUAAAGAGGUGUAAAGAG
```

Expected result:

```
GUCACACAGACAGAUGUAGAGCAAAGGCAACA
```

I haven't encountered any other cases where the code will not work.

Comment: Use a regular expression: `GUGU(.*?)AGAG`

Comment: You should use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for getting your code reviewed.

Comment: @PrasadK CR is not for help fixing bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work if `AGAG` is right before `GUGU`. After the first iteration on that input, the value of `strand` is

```
GUCACACAGACAGAUGUAGAGGUGUUGUGUAACCCGUAGAGCAAAGGCAACAGUGUGUAAAGAGGUGUAAAGAG
```

Then `initial` is `21` and `final` is `17`, so you do:

```
strand = strand[:21] + strand[21:]
```

which just sets `strand` back to the same value, so you get stuck in a loop.

The `string.find()` method has an optional `start` argument, so you can tell it to start looking for `AGAG` after `initial`:

```
final = strand.find("AGAG", initial+4)
```

You can also do the whole thing with a regexp substitution:

```
import re
strand = re.sub(r'GUGU(.*?)AGAG', '', strand)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the following: final = strand.find("AGAG", initial+4)

Comment: I thought I did explain it. That's the optional `start` argument, which tells `find` where to start looking for `AGAG`. So it starts looking after the `GUGU`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pattern = '(.*?)GUGU.*?AGAG'
s1 = 'AGCGUGUGAGAGCUCCGA'
s2 = 'GUGUAGAGGUCACAGUGUAAAAGCUCUAGAGCAGACAGAUGUAGAGGUGUUGUGUAACCCGUAGAGCAAAGGCAACAGUGUGUAAAGAGGUGUAAAGAG'
print ''.join(re.findall(pattern,s1)) + s1[s1.rfind('AGAG')+4:]
print ''.join(re.findall(pattern,s2)) + s2[s2.rfind('AGAG')+4:]
```

> AGCCUCCGA 
>   GUCACACAGACAGAUGUAGAGCAAAGGCAACA